# Complex impedance triangle, why is there a complex part?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits

Why is the inductive reactance written as jωL?

I know that multiplying by j rotates the inductive reactance on the j axis, but why do we do that?

Why is it not on the same axis as the resistance?

Answer (score 1):

First a minor quibble.  Reactance is the imaginary part of impedance and is thus *real*.

$$Z = R + jX$$

Thus, inductive reactance is:

$$X_L = \omega L$$

Second, *reactance is the imaginary part of impedance*.  So, to fully understand why this is, you must understand the notion of *impedance*.

For the ideal inductor, we have that the voltage across is proportional to the *rate of change* of current through:

$$v_L = L \dfrac{di_L}{dt}$$

Thus, in general, the voltage and current do not have the same form.

However, there is a special class of waveforms such that the inductor voltage and current *are* of the same form:

Let $i_L(t) = Ie^{st}$ where *s* is a complex number $s = \sigma + j \omega$.  Then note that:

$$v_L(t) = L \dfrac{dIe^{st}}{dt} = sLIe^{st} = sLi_L(t)$$

In other words, for complex exponential excitation, the inductor voltage and current are *proportional*:

$$ \dfrac{v_L}{i_L} = sL = Z_L$$

where $Z_L$, the constant of proportionality, is called the *impedance* of the inductor.

Remember, $s = \sigma + j \omega$ is a complex number and thus

$$Z_L = \sigma L + j \omega L$$.

Recognize that the imaginary part is the inductive reactance

$$X_L = \omega L$$.

To make contact with AC circuits, note that if keep $s$ purely imaginary by setting $\sigma = 0$, we have by Euler's formula

$$e^{j\omega t} = \cos \omega t + j \sin \omega t$$

So, we can study the behaviour of circuits under sinusuoidal excitation by "pretending" that the circuit is excited by sources of the form $e^{j\omega t}$, solving with impedances, and then recovering the time domain solution by *simply take the real part at the end*.  This is called [phasor analysis](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-use-phasors-for-circuit-analysis.html).

Answer (score 0):

Because the voltage across an inductor leads the current by $\pi/2$ in phase, *i.e.* it is a quarter of a cycle ahead. $\arg(Z)$, where $Z$ is the complex impedance, is the voltage's phase relative to that of the current. In using the phasor notation, one represents a quantity $x(t) =A \cos(\omega\,t+\delta)$ varying sinusoidally varying with time by the phasor $A\,e^{i\omega\,t}$. Whenever we do calculations involving wholy linear operations, such as solving differential equations through all the operations of calculus, we get the same answer whether we represent $x(t)$ as $A\,e^{i\omega\,t}$ and recover the real part of the result at the end of the calculation or whether we do it with the $A \cos(\omega\,t+\delta)$ representation. The complex representation is easier to calculate with, since phase shifts mean simple scaling by a number on the unit circle.

If you calculate the power through an impedance like an inductor where there is $\pi/2$ phase shift, the element sinks energy throughout one half of the period, but is a source of energy throughout the other half period. There is no nett energy loss: in an ideal inductor, the energy builds up the magnetic field in the inductor throughout one half period, and this energy of genesis is returned to the circuit throughout the other half period. This is very different from what happens in a resistor: the voltage and current in phase and the resistor is thus continuously converting electrical energy to heat.